# insert string before last line in freebsd

Tags: unix, sed, freebsd

I got file with next content:

```
protocol static {
        route 100.100.100.100/32 via 192.168.56.2;
        route 1.1.1.1/32 via 10.0.2.15; 
}
```

And I need to add one route string

```
a.b.c.d/32 via a.b.c.d
```

after

`route 1.1.1.1/32 via 10.0.2.15;`

How can I do it?

Comment: Could you clarify where the problem is. Obviously you could use any text editor, but my guess is, that this is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_bsd.html). The module [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html#lineinfile-manage-lines-in-text-files) does exactly what you need.

Simple playbook below adds the line to the file */scratch/route.cfg* at host *test_01*

```
> cat play.yml
- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        path: /scratch/route.cfg
        regexp: "^\\s*route a.b.c.d/32\\s*via"
        line: "        route a.b.c.d/32 via a.b.c.d;"
        insertafter: "^\\s*route 1.1.1.1/32\\s*via"
```

.

```
> ansible-playbook play.yml
PLAY [test_01] 
******************************************************************************
TASK [lineinfile] 
***************************************************************************
changed: [test_01]
PLAY RECAP 
*************************************************************************
test_01                    : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

with the result

```
# cat route.cfg
protocol static {
        route 100.100.100.100/32 via 192.168.56.2;
        route 1.1.1.1/32 via 10.0.2.15; 
        route a.b.c.d/32 via a.b.c.d;
}
```

FWIW. Lot of details how to use FreeBSD and Ansible can be found in the Ansible role [freebsd_postinstall](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-freebsd-postinstall)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '\Xroute 1.1.1.1/32 via 10.0.2.15;Xa\
a.b.c.d/32 via a.b.c.d;
' protstat
```

The `\X` choose regexp delimiter to `X`, after it you can find your pattern, after it `X` (closing regexp), and an `a` (append). It followed by a backslash (`\`) and a newline(!), after it your new rule, after it a newline and an apostroph. The `protstat` is your filename.

If you want modify inplace you should add `-ibak` to `sed`'s options - in this case you'll have `protstatbak` backup file. If you want omit the backup you should add `-i""` (empty suffix).